# Placement of formatted bibliographic entries on a beamer slide

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, positioning

I am writing presentation in LaTeX, using the `beamer` document class.

In the attached screenshot you can see two entries of the list of references. However, they are placed in the middle of a slide. I am wondering is it possible to place it at the top of slide? I want to do this only to this one single slide.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use positioning options: those for the frame override the global placement policy.

```latex
\begin{frame}[t]{References}
  \begin{thebibliography}{12}
    \bibitem{foo}[bar]
    % etc.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
```

Possible values are: `t`op, `b`ottom, `c`enter, of course. But there's also `s`trechable to use in conjunction with `\vfill` or similar in the content.
You may also adjust with `allowframebreaks=0.7` or other fraction.
Multiple options are separated with coma.